# TypeError:Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map') in recatjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mapping

I get this error called Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')
this is my code please help me fix it

```js
return (
    <div className="row">
      <h3>{title}</h3>

      <div className="row__posters">
      {movies.map(movie => {
          return <img
            className={`row_poster`}
            src={`${base_url}`}
            alt={movie.name} />
        })}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
```

[image]

Comment: Please provide, how you declare `movies`.

Answer (score 1):

try movies?.map or

````
if(movies == undefined){
return;
}

return (
    <div className="row">
      <h3>{title}</h3>

      <div className="row__posters">
      {movies.map(movie => {
          return <img
            className={`row_poster`}
            src={`${base_url}`}
            alt={movie.name} />
        })}
      </div>
    </div>
  );```
````

Answer (score 1):

**change :**

```
{movies.map(movie => {
          return <img
            className={`row_poster`}
            src={`${base_url}`}
            alt={movie.name} />
        })}
```

**to  :**

```
{movies && movies.map(movie => {
          return <img
            className={`row_poster`}
            src={`${base_url}`}
            alt={movie.name} />
        })}
```